# C - malloc/free on a struct containing struct types

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc, free

I have a quick question about how to properly `free` pointers to struct types. Using an example of a linked list, say there were:

```
struct l_node {
    int data; 
    struct l_node *next; 
    struct l_node *prev; 
}; 

typedef struct l_node node;

struct l_list {
    node *head; 
    node *tail; 
};

typedef struct l_list llist;
```

If I had a function, call it `make_list` that calls `malloc` only to allocate space for a llist type, and not the node types that are inside it, do I need to call `free` for the two node pointers inside `struct l_node` as well as for the list, or since I don't call `malloc` for them, is it OK not to `free`?

Comment: You `free` what you `malloc`.

Comment: I would not free next and prev as part of freeing the current node.  They should be freed in a function identical to the one that frees the current node.  If the current node is freed, it will not leave those structs hanging because you should have references to them somewhere else.

Comment: @Haroogan Yes, you should free what you malloc, but these objects aren't nested inside the current node, only a reference to them is.  Freeing early will leave pointers to freed memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `malloc` for obtaining a pointer, you should NOT `free` it, as this will cause undefined behaviour.
In order to not create memory leaks, you should `free` what you `malloc`ed.

Some library function will return pointers which also need to be freed, because they used malloc to create the pointer for you. `strdup` is such an example.